# Symbolic reduce of augmented matrices with TensorReduce

Tags: symbolic, tensors

I am trying to reduce a symbolic matrix expression containing augmented/concatenated matrices using TensorReduce, but it does not behave as expected when transposing an augmented matrix.

I assume the problem is that building a matrix from multiple submatrices creates a tensor of higher dimension instead of a bigger 2d tensor, but I do not know how to create a symbolic 2d tensor from multiple smaller symbolic 2d tensors.

As an example

```
$Assumptions = {
    Element[P, Matrices[{n, n}]]
};
TensorReduce[Transpose[{{P, P}}]]
```

yields

```
{{P}, {P}}
```

and not

```
{{Transpose[P]}, {Transpose[P]}}
```

which is the result I would expect.

Answer (score 1):

The tensor functionality will not produce a mixed output of explicit and symbolic matrices. That is, the tensor will remain symbolic unless all of the parts are explicit matrices/arrays. Also, it is better to use [`TensorTranspose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorTranspose) instead of [`Transpose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose) when dealing with tensors. At any rate, we can write your expression as both a mixed expression and as a tensor expression as follows:

```
mixed = {{P, P}};
tensor = TensorProduct[{{1, 1}}, P];
```

Let's check that the two are equivalent by substituting an explicit matrix for `P`:

```
mixed == tensor /. P->Array[a, {3,3}]
```

> True

Now, the tensor framework, and in particular [`TensorTranspose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorTranspose), does not know how to deal with this mixed form. For example:

```
$Assumptions = P ∈ Arrays[{n, n}];
TensorTranspose[{{P, P}}, {1, 2, 4, 3}]
```

> TensorTranspose::lowlen: Required length 2 is smaller than maximum 4 of support of {1,2,4,3}.
>
> TensorTranspose[{{P, P}}, {1, 2, 4, 3}]

On the other hand, [`TensorTranspose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorTranspose) (as well as [`Transpose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose)) knows how to deal with the tensor form:

```
transpose = TensorReduce @ TensorTranspose[tensor, {1, 2, 4, 3}]
```

> TensorTranspose[P \[TensorProduct] {{1, 1}}, {4, 3, 1, 2}]

Let's check that this agrees with your expected result when substituting an explicit matrix for `P`:

```
expected = {{Transpose[P], Transpose[P]}};
expected == transpose /. P->Array[a, {3,3}]
```

> True

Summarizing, if you use:

```
TensorProduct[{{1, 1}}, P]
```

instead of:

```
{{P, P}}
```

then the tensor framework is more likely able to do some transformations of the input.

Answer (score 0):

What you are expecting does not happen for a number of reasons.  Firstly, I think, `Transpose` operates on the assumption that the elements of the list are scalars, regardless of any assumption you give.

```
Assuming[Element[P, Matrices[{n, n}]], Transpose[{{P, P}}]]
(* {{P}, {P}} *)
```

`TensorReduce` has nothing left to do here.

Further, according to the documentation, `Transpose` "transposes the first two levels in list".  This means that

```
 With[{P = Array[a, {2, 2}]}, Print[P]; Transpose[{{P, P}}]]

(* {{a[1,1],a[1,2]},{a[2,1],a[2,2]}} *)
(* {{{{a[1, 1], a[1, 2]}, {a[2, 1], a[2, 2]}}}, {{{a[1, 1], 
    a[1, 2]}, {a[2, 1], a[2, 2]}}}} *)
```

So the matrices inside do not get transposed.